# как переписать jquery на javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$("form").submit(function() { //Change
        var th = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "mail.php", //Change
            data: th.serialize()
        }).done(function() {
            alert("Thank you!");
            setTimeout(function() {
                // Done Functions
                th.trigger("reset");
            }, 1000);
        });
        return false;
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Как сделать тоже самое на js?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_forms_through_JavaScript

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Answer (score 3):

Пойдём по порядку:

- `$("form")` - это ничто иное как [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector). Значит пишем `document.querySelector('form')`. НО! Это вам вернёт первый попавшийся `<form>...</form>`. Так что если вам надо чтобы все формы при сабмите вызывали одну и ту же ф-ию, то вам надо использовать [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), который вернёт список всех форм в виде [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList). Но к счастью у него есть метод [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach), так вам просто надо будет запустить следующие шаги внутри метода `forEach`
- `.submit(...)` - это тоже самое, что назначить слушатель (ВАЖНО что внутри скобок есть ф-ия  иначе это будет вызов события `submit`). Значит у нас есть 2 возможности:

  1. [form.addEventListener('submit')](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
  2. [form.onsubmit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onsubmit)

  Про их разницу очень подробно можно прочитать [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick) и в разных вариациях этот вопрос уже обсуждался 100500 раз, так что думаю найти инфу будет не проблема :). Но если прям очень в кратце, с помощью метода 1 можно задать несколько обработчиков на 1 событие, а с помощью метода 2 только 1 обработчик можно навесить, причём он перетерёт то что было до него. **Повторюсь** это очень в кратце для общего понимания, лучше прочитайте дополнительно
- `var th = $(this);` - мы так же можем заменить разными способами в зависимости от того в каком виде ф-ия была передана в слушатель:

  1. Если была передана ф-ия вида `function() {...}`, тогда у нас единнственный способ замены это:

     1. `const target = this`
  2. Если была передана ф-ия вида `function(e) {...}`, тогда у нас два способа замены это:

     1. `const target = this`
     2. `const target = e.target`
  3. Если была передана ф-ия вида `() => {...}`, тогда мы не сможем ни на что заменить, т.к. у стрелочной ф-ии нет `this` и не был передан `EventTarget`. Но есть небольшая хитрость, если заранее сохранить найденную форму в какую-то переменную, то можно обратиться к ней. В случае с `forEach` даже отдельно перезаписывать не придётся т.к. нужный элемент уже будет передан в начале методе. Так что если у нас где-то заранее была сохранена форма, то у нас единнственный способ замены это:

     1. `const target = form`
  4. Если была передана ф-ия вида `(e) => {...}`, тогда у нас единнственный способ замены это:

     1. `const target = e.target`

  Подробнее про всё это можно прочитать [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#other_notes)
- `th.serialize()` - заменям на `new FormData(target)`

  Подробнее можно прочитать [тут](https://javascript.info/formdata), [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects), [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_forms_through_JavaScript#using_xmlhttprequest_and_the_formdata_object) и [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46640024/how-do-i-post-form-data-with-fetch-api)
- `$.ajax({TYPE, URL, DATA})` - заменяем на `fetch(URL, {method: TYPE, body: new FormData(target)})`
- `.done(...)` - заменеяем на `.then(res => res.json()).then(...)`
- `th.trigger("reset");` - заменяем на `target.reset();`
- Ну и не забываем `return false` в конце, чтобы страница не перезагружалась после сабмита формы

Comment: `заменеяем на .then(res => res.json()).then(...)` а каким боком сюда JSON пришел?)

Comment: @OliverPatterson Потому что `$.ajax` - это делает неявно, а в синтаксисе `fetch` - это надо делать вручную

Comment: Так, а если ответ не JSON, а текст какой-то?

Comment: @OliverPatterson Спарведливое замечание) Привык, что получаю все данные только в виде `JSON`) Поправьте этот пункт, пожалуйста, если вам не трудно

Comment: [Сделал так](https://codepen.io/slagrach/pen/mdXKZbW)  выдает ошибку [![][1]][1]

Comment: "Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input" не знаю как картинку добавить сюда